# How to Create ArrayList<Player> Spigot 1.12.2 - Java 8?

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, minecraft

I am having trouble creating an `ArrayList<Player>` in [Spigot 1.12.2](https://getbukkit.org/get/Fpt2yFn7HRTrot5uE1b8NFWtpQlYITgK). I am currently using the `Java 8 version 231` to compile the plugin because it depends on `Java 8`. When I try to make this code:

```
ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();

for (Player p : players) {
    getServer().broadcastMessage(p.getDisplayName + " Is Online!");
}
```

There are errors telling me to compile the project for `JRE 1.5`. I did that, but it didn't work showing errors in CMD when starting the server. I've been trying this for a few months now and I'm not getting it.

In `JAVA 7` along with `Spigot 1.5.2` I was able to make the above code work smoothly, with `JAVA 8` and the `Spigot` upgrade to version `1.12.2` changed a lot that I don't know.

Can anyone help me get the list of online players and save it to a `List` so I can loop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your code is currently written, it will simply terminate since that is an empty list and the message will never get sent to any of the players.

Spigot already has a method [`Server#getOnlinePlayers()`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/Server.html#getOnlinePlayers--) which you can iterate through using a for each loop.

With that you don't even need to construct a new ArrayList you can simply do

```
for(Player p : getServer().getOnlinePlayers()) {
   // Do stuff
}
```

Hope this helps!